# Verifying the countably additive measure property of $\nu_f$ when $\nu_f(E)$ is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am studying measure theory and have come across a problem where I am asked to show that a certain function $\nu_f$ is a measure. Specifically, let $f \in L^+((X, \mathcal{M}, \mu))$; for any $E \in \mathcal{M}$, $\nu_f$ is defined by

$$\nu_f(E) = \int_E f  d\mu.$$

I've found related questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946966/is-nue-int-e-f-d-mu-a-measure-on-omega), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685990/proof-verification-that-mu-fe-int-e-f-d-lambda-is-a-measure-on), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508402/using-thm-13-on-pg-374-in-royden-and-fitzpatrick-real-analysis-fourth-edition), however I'm still a little confused. I understand that to show $\nu_f$ is a measure, I need to show that it is non-negative, $\nu_f(\emptyset) = 0$, and countably additive. I believe I can show that $\nu_f(\emptyset) = 0$, but I would like confirmation on this
$$\nu_f(\emptyset) = \int_{\emptyset} f d\mu = \int f \chi_{\emptyset} d\mu = \int \chi_{\emptyset} d\mu = \mu(\emptyset) = 0.$$

I've found Theorem 20 from *Real Analysis, 4rth edition* by Royden and Fitzpatrick,

> **Theorem 20 (the Countable Additivity of Integration)** *Let $f$ be integrable over $E$ and $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a disjoint countable collection of measurable subsets of $E$ whose union is $E$. Then* $$\int_E f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{E_n} f.$$ which states the countable additivity of integration for an integrable function over a set $E$. The definition of integrable, according to the same text, requires that $\int_E f < \infty$.

My main concern arises with the countable additivity property, Theorem 20 covers when $\nu_f(E)$ is finite, but what about when $\nu_f(E)$ is infinite. $L^+$ is the space of all measurable functions from $X$ to $[0,\infty]$, with $\infty$ included, not $[0,\infty)$. Can I apply Theorem 20 to show that $\nu_f$ is countably additive in the case where $\nu_f(E)$ is infinite? If not, how should I approach showing countable additivity in this scenario?

Any insights or suggestions on how to proceed with proving that $\nu_f$ is a measure would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Fubini Tonelli applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Theorem you quote does not need integrability when $f$ is non-negative; because in that situation you can apply Monotone Convergence.

Comment: Thank you! much appreciated! I read the whole Lebesgue Integration section in Royden and Fitzgerald and, it makes much more sense now, the proof of Theorem 20 is set up to fit with the Monotone Convergence Theorem above it for f nonnegative

Comment: Indeed. Monotone and Dominated Convergence are the bread and butter of Measure Theory.

Comment: Agreed, I'm starting to realize that, does my proof that $\nu_f(\emptyset) = 0$ look okay?

Comment: It's fine, but you can shorten it slightly if you notice that $\chi_\emptyset=0$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again, it's been two days of reading.